dynamically modify the value in jqgrid
I have two grids, in first I select a value and in second I display the same row but make it editable. It looks like this:
jQuery("#GridSelectedProducts").jqGrid({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    autowidth: true,
    regional: 'en',
    /*data:{},*/
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['id', 'productid', 'opportunityproductid', 'Product', 'Product-Title', 'Unit', 'defaultunit', 'uomid', 'Override-Product', 'Price', 'Qty', 'Volumes-Discount', 'Amount', 'Discount-Type', 'Discount', 'Total-After-Discount', 'Cost-Amount', 'Margin', 'Percentage', 'Revenue-Stream', 'Licensing'],
    colModel: SelectedProductsModel,
    mtype: 'Post',
    id: "pw_id",
    viewrecords: true,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#pager10_d',
    sortable: true,
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    multiselect: false,
    forceFit: true,
    cellEdit: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    afterSaveCell: Calcul,
    loadComplete: $("a").click(),
    caption: "Selected Products"
}).navGrid('#pager10_d', {
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: true,
    refresh: false // NPI : remove refresh button because it empty lines when used on newed added row configured !
});

Revenue Stream and Licensing are drop down fields. I would like to hide specific values in Licensing based on the selected value in Revenue Stream. I couldn't find any resources or articles or questions where I would find that kind of behavior, do you have any idea how can I achieve it ?

After spending a lot of time on this matter I have finally arrived to the solution that works for me and I want to share it with you.
Apparently jqGrid has options for when the grid rendering is happening.
jQuery(#"YourLovelyGrid").jqGrid({ 
 height: '',
 width: '',
 // a lot of other options
});

I found out that there are events which can also be attached to the above code, those events look like this:

onSelectCell: This event is triggered when a cell is selected. It provides the rowid and the name of the selected cell.
beforeSaveCell: This event is triggered before a cell is saved (i.e., after editing). It allows you to perform actions or validations
before the cell data is saved.
afterSaveCell: This event is triggered after a cell is saved (i.e., after editing). It allows you to perform actions after the cell
data has been saved.
beforeSelectCell: This event is triggered before a cell is selected. It allows you to perform actions or validations before a
cell is selected.
afterEditCell: This event is triggered after a cell is edited. It provides the rowid and cellname of the edited cell.

I used this information to achieve my desired behavior.
I have added the logic to beforeEditCell - in here I check if I'm editing my desired cell let's call it X. If when trying to edit X- rowData.Y equals some specific values I attach read only class to the cell and return false(I suppose this is required for jqgrid to function correctly).
beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var rowData = $("#GridSelectedProducts").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);

    if (cellname === 'Licensing') {
        if (rowData.RevenueStream === "Licenses" || rowData.RevenueStream === "Software Updates") 
            return true;
        else {
            $("#GridSelectedProducts").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'Licensing', '', '', {
                'class': 'readonly-cell',
            });

            return false;
        }
    }
}

Read only class is pretty simple:
.read-only-cell {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    pointer-events: none;   
}

If you would like to clear values based on what you chose in Y cell- you can manipulate with afterEditCell or afterSaveCell, at this moment I can't really identify how control focus and those two events are related. They have pretty random behavior.
